# Elaat (of HighFleet) is a large planet (6.6x Earth), but much less dense than Earth. Are there such rocky planets?

Tags: biology, gravity, rockets

According to [this reddit post](https://old.reddit.com/r/Highfleet/comments/rfek2x/lore_elaat_has_a_circumference_of_15975826_mi/hoeih55/?context=3), Elaat, the fictional world of HighFleet ([steam link](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1434950/HighFleet/), [humble bundle](https://www.humblebundle.com/store/highfleet)), is 159758.26 mi around. Compared to Earth's ~24,000 miles. (about 6.6x)

Yet in game, large thruster-driven airships hover and fly using forces not too much larger than current rocket engines (perhaps 5x as a function of weight), but with ship weights significantly larger (1000x). In game, during landings, you can see that the downward acceleration is nowhere near the $9\frac{m}{s^2}$ that occurs on Earth. It is perhaps 1/2 that or 1/4 that, which might explain how the ships stay aloft and why rocket airships are the preferred bulk cargo transports.

So, we apparently have a planet that is 6x radius, but contains roughly **EDIT: 10-20x** the mass.

**Do we see evidence of such planets that would be roughly human livable perhaps after teraforming?**

or

**What would it take (physically) to have a planet that supports human life, but also rocket airships of the 1000s of tons size that can travel 100s-1000s of km in powered flight**

Are there other factors that could explain the reduced downward acceleration?

Some other factors that may be relevant.

- The planet is apparently a desert, but not scorchingly hot
- The planet apparently has significant bounties of liquid methane (LCH4)
- The planet has rather significant uranium, enough to have a prolific nuclear stockpile in post-cataclysm (a non-nuclear cataclysm)
- Radio waves apparently proliferate normally, so radar and long range radio is normal
- The day/night cycle seems to be close to Earths

EDIT: Thanks to commenters, using Newtons equation I estimate it's actually 10-20x the mass of Earth, but still 6.6x the radius.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like it's asking about an existing work of fiction not asking about building a fictional world. Such questions are off topic her.

Comment: Ah, fair enough.

Comment: Also worth noting that 1/4 G at surface for a planet that large does *not* imply 1/4 the Earth's mass -- go look up Newton's gravitation equation and see what mass that takes at that radius compared to Earth's figures.

Comment: you're right, obviously wrong, given we know radius is 6x larger. Thanks!

Comment: OP is asking if a planet with certain properties exist.

Comment: @L.Dutch Sure but that Q by itself isn't a worldbuilding question. If I asked if a planet from a work of fiction could exist I'm not asking about building a world. I'm asking about an existing work of fiction. Last I checked, "could the forest moon of Endor exist?" was off topic.

Comment: The equatorial circumference of Earth is 24,901.461 mi, so Elaat has 6.415 times the cirfumference and diameter, 41.152 times the surface area, and 263.99152 times the volume of Earth.  If it has as much as 20 times the mass of Earth it will have  0.07576  times the density  & thus a density of only 0.4177 grams per cubic centimeter.  It would be more dense than hydrogen or helium but less dense than lithium.  Water has a higher density than that.  I don't know how the planet could have liquid or solid surface.

Comment: @JoshVanderHook if you were to ask simply if a planet with certain features is realistic, without any reference to existing fictional worlds, the question would be accepted. Just for future reference, as L.Dutch's answer already has it covered ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 6x radius, but contains roughly 1/2 or 1/4 the mass.

That's impossible: for  $6^3 = $216 times the volume and half the mass of Earth, you would get an average density of

$\rho'=(1/2 \ m_E)/(216 V_E)=1/432 \ m_E/V_E = 1/432 \ \rho_E$.

Considering that the average density of Earth is 5.5 $g/cm^3$, the planet should be made of something with a density of 0.01 $g/cm^3$, 8 times less dense than hydrogen at standard temperature and pressure.

If that thing is something, it is not a planet.

If the mass is 10 $m_E$,, you still end up with a density of about 0.2 $g/cm^3$, which is rather low. For a reference Saturn, the least dense planet in our solar system, has a density of 0.7 $g/cm^3$.

Comment: I was wrong about it being half the mass. See comments to my post. Nearest I can work out is it's approximately 10x the mass to get 1/4 g at the surface (which is 6.6 x as far as earth's surface would be from the center). That'd be ... close to hydrogen. Or perhaps double that. Does that change your thoughts?

Comment: @JoshVanderHook, the formula to use is right there. If instead of 0.5 $m_E$ you have 10 $m_E$, you still end up with a density of 1/20 of Earth, about 1/5 of the density of water.

Comment: That is understood. You're implying that means no, there's no such planet.